# PROBLEMS WHEN SETTINGUP YOLOX

Tags: python, yolo

could somebody help me with this?
I just simple follow the instruction of megvii

```py
python setup.py develop
```

the problem comeup:

```
(newtorch) PS D:\codeofpaper\YOLOX-main> python setup.py develop
running develop
running egg_info
writing yolox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to yolox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to yolox.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'yolox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'yolox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 63, in <module>
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 34, in run
    self.install_for_development()
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 114, in install_for_development
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 309, in run
    force=self.force)
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1032, in new_compiler
    return klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 285, in __init__
    CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
  File "D:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\envs\newtorch\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 129, in __init__
    if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

MY CMDline output
I don't kbow what to do?
My cp is Windows10,and I use anaconda virtual env

Comment: Could you please share the setup.py file? It would help to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `gcc` was not found on your computer, i.e. `cygwin` is not set up correctly. `distutils` tries to find the version with [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/54ab9ad312ea53db40e31712454272e1d4c0315f/Lib/distutils/cygwinccompiler.py#L397):

```
commands = ['gcc -dumpversion', 'ld -v', 'dllwrap --version']
return tuple([_find_exe_version(cmd) for cmd in commands])
```

So make sure that your PATH is set up correctly so that you can run these commands from the same terminal from which you executed your `pip install`

Comment: Thanks a lot anayway!!!  I didn't fix it at last. However I solve my problem by reinstalling my Visual Studio.